# BigQuery flatten JSON text into array of struct / record

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

So I have a raw table with 2 columns:

```
id (INT64)  |  content (STRING)
------------|--------------------
1           | {"photos": [{"location": {"lat": 111, "lon": 222}, "ts": "2019-12-16", "uri": "aaa"}, {"location": {"lat": 333, "lon": 444}, "ts": "2019-12-17", "uri": "bbb"}]}
------------|--------------------
2           | ....
```

First column is an integer-typed id, second column is json-formatted string. An example json looks like this:

```
{
  "photos": [
    {
      "location": {
        "lat": 111, 
        "lon": 222
      }, 
      "ts": "2019-12-16", 
      "uri": "aaa"
    }, 
    {
      "location": {
        "lat": 333, 
        "lon": 444
      }, 
      "ts": "2019-12-17", 
      "uri": "bbb"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Question

How can I format the photos from the raw table into an array of structs/records, i.e. resulting in something like this?

```
id     |  photos.ts    | photos.uri  |  photos.location.lat  | photos.location.lon
-------|---------------|-------------|-----------------------|--------------------
1      |  2019-12-16   | aaa         |                   111 |                222
       |  2019-12-17   | bbb         |                   333 |                444
-------|---------------|-------------|-----------------------|--------------------
2      | ...           | ...         |                   ... |                ...
```

### Thoughts

1. `JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.photos")` seems to be a good start as it would give me a JSON object array, then I'd need some JS UDF to format the result into BQ `STRUCT`/`RECORD` type. Not sure exactly how to do that though -- any help is appreciated!
2. I'm not sure if this "cleanup" into `STRUCT`/`RECORD` is really necessary or worth it. It seems that I can just format photos into an array of `STRING`:

```
id (INT64)  |  photos (STRING)
------------|--------------------
1           | {"location": {"lat": 111, "lon": 222}, "ts": "2019-12-16", "uri": "aaa"}
            | {"location": {"lat": 333, "lon": 444}, "ts": "2019-12-17", "uri": "bbb"}
------------|--------------------
2           | ....
```

, then use `JSON_EXTRACT/JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` in my analytical queries. How big a performance sacrifice would I expect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(json).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"photos": [{"location": {"lat": 111, "lon": 222}, "ts": "2019-12-16", "uri": "aaa"}, {"location": {"lat": 333, "lon": 444}, "ts": "2019-12-17", "uri": "bbb"}]}' content
)
SELECT id, json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.photos")) AS photos
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id  photos   
1   1   {"location":{"lat":111,"lon":222},"ts":"2019-12-16","uri":"aaa"}     
        {"location":{"lat":333,"lon":444},"ts":"2019-12-17","uri":"bbb"}
```

OR ... you can go further with below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(json).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
"""; 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"photos": [{"location": {"lat": 111, "lon": 222}, "ts": "2019-12-16", "uri": "aaa"}, {"location": {"lat": 333, "lon": 444}, "ts": "2019-12-17", "uri": "bbb"}]}' content
)
SELECT id, 
  array(
    SELECT AS struct
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(photo, "$.ts") ts,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(photo, "$.uri") uri,
      STRUCT(JSON_EXTRACT(photo, "$.location.lat") AS lat, JSON_EXTRACT(photo, "$.location.lon") AS lon) AS location
    FROM unnest(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(content, "$.photos"))) photo
  ) AS photos

FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

which returns

```
Row id  photos.ts       photos.uri  photos.location.lat photos.location.lon  
1   1   2019-12-16      aaa         111                 222  
        2019-12-17      bbb         333                 444
```

Comment: exactly what I was asking for!

Comment: Can you include an example on how to run this query on the entire table?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.